# Centering a Placeholder and Input Text in a Text Field

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to center a placeholder and the input which the user will enter in the Text Field. I imagine it would be possible yet I cant figure it out. could anyone help? my code for the Text Field in question is below...

```
<input type="text" style="font-weight:bold:" name="kword" id="kword" autofocus ="on" placeholder="Enter Keyword(s)" autocomplete ="on"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Aside from adding padding-left equal to the amount that the word appears in the center, this might not be possible with CSS alone.

Comment: I believe your looking for something like this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ Because its a new feature it's not fully browser compatible, but in browsers that support the placeholder attribute this will let you style it how you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be used to `text-align:center`

CSS:

```
input, input[placeholder] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Target the browser-specific placeholder pseudo-element like this:

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  text-align: center;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  text-align: center;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="font-weight:bold;" placeholder="Enter Keyword(s)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a good solution was :

```
div.search {display: flex;}

input::placeholder {align-self: center;}
```